# Can't create an outlet by drag and drop ,Xcode 6

Tags: ios

I'm new to IOS XCODE6 ,trying to create a single view app .
When I try to create an outlet connection to the label by drag and drop ,
nothing shows up as you see in the picture below.
I did search the web all over to find an answer but nothing worked.
I'm working from a text book which is made for beginners,following all instructions and nothing there mentioned about this issue.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks .

[image]

Comment: `LaunchScreen.xib` do not belongs to `ViewController` class... Check out `Main.storyboard`, there You'll have a screen with `ViewController` as the owner. P.S.1 right now storyboards are mostly used instead of xibs. P.S.2. I'm voting to close because this question should be asked on www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've managed to solve this issue already, but I just had a eureka moment myself. The problem with dragging-and-dropping was that I have re-assigned the left and right click on my trackpad, which ultimately led me to my solution (albeit in Xcode 7).

To create an outlet, try to **Control + Right-Click** (or whatever your Mac's right click is set as - you should be able to find this in the System Preferences).

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController.h set the property for your label as:

@interface

@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end

Now, in the ViewController.m do the following:

@implementation

@synthesize label;

@end

Next go to your XIB file
Right click on the FileOwner Icon on the Left.Here You will see the property that you had set.Just Drag the connection to the Label you have created in the Xib file.and it should Work

Comment: I know I can write the outlet connection manually ,the thing is that I want to use the drag and drop technique.

Comment: @sunflower You are trying to drag and drop connection on launch screen xib from view controller which cannot be done.Please create a view controller xib and then try to drag and drop connections.

Answer (score 0):

LaunchScreen.xib (use Main.storyboard) class is UIView and you are trying to connect it to a ViewController. You have to change the class of your xib and match it to your ViewController class.

Comment: I did this and it's still not working,it works only when I use the story board .

Comment: The text book said to create the outlet connections with drag and drop from the .xib file but some developers told me that the .xib doesn't allow this and it is only allowed from the storyboard.Have no idea why ?